# how to implement exponential backoff in amazon sqs without writing code

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have a simple task that requires a 3rd party. 
When a request comes, I push it to an `amazon sqs` queue, pull it in a worker and call the `3rd party`. In case of a time out, I want to implement an exponential backoff (try again in 2 secs, then 4 then 8, then...)
with a max retry.

Using `python`, `boto -> sqs`

I've looked for built in parameters to allow me to do so with as little code as possible (**ideally, no code at all**).

Something like

```
from boto import sqs

def handle_message(message):
    try:
      # send a post to api
    except TimeOut, err:
      # send_back_to_itself in 2/4/8 sec
      if delay < DELAY_LIMIT:
          queue.write(message, delay=secs)
```

Comment: You're asking how to implement backoff/retry for the HTTP POST to the 3rd-party API, right? (not via boto3 to SQS) There are NPM modules that do this, for example: https://github.com/FGRibreau/node-request-retry

Comment: You would need to delete the message before writing it back to the queue, which is risky as it's not an atomic update.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

According to the [AWS SDK docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/api-retries.html), you get exponential backoff for free if you're using one of the official SDK libraries.  So it seems all you need to do is set your `max_attempts` count, and everything after the first attempt will back off exponentially:

```
import boto3
from botocore.config import Config

config = Config(
    retries = dict(
        max_attempts = 10   # docs say default is 5
    )
)

sqs = boto3.client('sqs', config=config)
sqs.receive_message(QueueUrl='https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/<your-account-num>/foobar')
```

Comment: OP is asking for waiting for an exponentially increasing amount of time before reprocessing the SQS message, not for exponentially waiting against responses from the SQS API.

Comment: Any code examples to configure this in spring boot java?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think "no code at all" is possible as of summer 2021. But there is a great blog post on how to do this with coding examples https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-sqs-dead-letter-queues-to-replay-messages/

Code sample from the link above:

```
def handler(event, context):
    """Lambda function handler."""
    for record in event['Records']:
        nbReplay = 0
        # number of replay
        if 'sqs-dlq-replay-nb' in record['messageAttributes']:
            nbReplay = int(record['messageAttributes']['sqs-dlq-replay-nb']["stringValue"])

        nbReplay += 1
        if nbReplay > config.MAX_ATTEMPS:
            raise MaxAttempsError(replay=nbReplay, max=config.MAX_ATTEMPS)

        # SQS attributes
        attributes = record['messageAttributes']
        attributes.update({'sqs-dlq-replay-nb': {'StringValue': str(nbReplay), 'DataType': 'Number'}})

        _sqs_attributes_cleaner(attributes)

        # Backoff
        b = backoff.ExpoBackoffFullJitter(base=config.BACKOFF_RATE, cap=config.MESSAGE_RETENTION_PERIOD)
        delaySeconds = b.backoff(n=int(nbReplay))

        # SQS
        SQS.send_message(
            QueueUrl=config.SQS_MAIN_URL,
            MessageBody=record['body'],
            DelaySeconds=int(delaySeconds),
            MessageAttributes=record['messageAttributes']
        )
```

Comment: An answer should provide some additional insight, not only a link. In my opinion "I think impossible." is not a contribution. That leaves this post a link-only answer, which risks being flagged as "not an answer" and being deleted.