# Is there a way I can get the current value SQS.Client.change_message_visibility

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I was reading [Changing the visibility timeout for a message instead of the queue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-visibility-timeout.html#changing-message-visibility-timeout), my idea is use this value for exponential backoff for each message, but in order to get it right I need to get the modify value not the global visibility timeout for example

- Visibility timeout queue 2 minutes for allow the 5 retries
- Visibility timeout message 10,20,40,80,160 (seconds)

but not see any method for such a thing, so my question is if there is a way I can get it, not sure this is the best approach but I was trying with this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48138094/how-to-implement-exponential-backoff-in-amazon-sqs-without-writing-code/48138954) but not sure which conditions needs to be done in order to fulfill this phrase "you get exponential backoff for free" because I am using boto3 and I am not getting exponential backoff

Comment: What if you will keep #attempts count within SQS message - in this case you dont need to read actual value, you need only write.

Comment: you say like a message attribute?, something like when I got a 500 error I would overwrite those two attributes in the message i.e. RETRY_COUNT and TIME_NEXT_RETRY and just check the count is not greater than what I expecting and the change visibility would be set to what I have in TIME_NEXT_RETRY

Comment: Something like that, yep

Comment: Sounds good, but now I have a couple of questions,  I am not getting the MessageAttributeNames where supposedly this attributes are, I am trying like this queue.receive_message(MessageAttributeNames=['All']) but not getting anything, I see the section in the Record where all the message is, do you know where I get it? and also you know if I can modify this value and how, if you wish I can modify the question properly

Comment: Im not using pyton, but I managed to google [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11913384/312041) for you